# Render and return Angular pages as API response

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, progressive-web-apps, angular-universal

Mobile App I’m developing needs to render html components inside it. 
Is it possible if I make Web API requests, render angular components and then return as HTML response from API?
[image]

Comment: Have you seen this https://universal.angular.io/

Comment: @Vikas I went through this and looks promissing.
But I couldn't find a way to sen a POST from API to Angular App.
Is that possible?